# MySQL inner join to sort parent, child and grand-child from the same table

Tags: mysql, join, parent-child, inner-join

MySQL database contains Countries, Town and Areas within the towns, all in the "mailshot" table. I want to return the whole set in order of descending granularity, using and inner join. I actually want to present the user with a drop down list for them to choose a Country or Town or Area within a town.

The data looks like this:

```
mailshot_id   mailshot_parent   mailshot_name   mailshot_level 
49              0               England         0
56              0               Scotland        0
140             49              London          1
149             49              York            1
191             56              Glasgow         1
300             140             Wimbledon       2
310             140             Westminster     2 
493             56              Edinburgh       1
```

and I want it output like this:

```
mailshot_id   mailshot_parent   mailshot_name   mailshot_level 
49              0               England         0
149             49              York            1
140             49              London          1
300             140             Wimbledon       2
310             140             Westminster     2 
56              0               Scotland        0
191             56              Glasgow         1
493             56              Edinburgh       1
```

I've almost got it with this:

```
 SELECT
    p.mailshot_id as p_id, 
    p.mailshot_name as p_name, 
    p.mailshot_level as p_level,
    p.mailshot_parent as p_parent, 
    c.mailshot_id as c_id, 
    c.mailshot_parent as c_parent, 
    c.mailshot_level as c_level, 
    c.mailshot_name as c_name, 
    case 
        WHEN p.mailshot_parent  = 0 THEN 
        p.mailshot_id 
        ELSE 
        p.mailshot_parent 
    END AS calcOrder 
FROM
    mailshot p LEFT JOIN mailshot c
    ON p.mailshot_id = c.mailshot_parent 
ORDER BY   calcOrder , p_id "
```

but it's not grouping the grandchildren records (level 2) close to the child records (level 1) I think the "case" part must be wrong, and I need to have some relationship between mailshot_id and parent_id dependent on level.  But I can't think if it.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: i dont see how you want the order , looks nothing ordered in your wished result. can you explain ?

Comment: can you give sample data of your tables , or if you want a fiddle example

Comment: Please, as *echo_Me* suggeste,  could you create a http://sqlfiddle.com with your tables and data sample in order to made some experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MySQL does not support hierarchicaly queries (no START WITH...CONNECT BY or CTE equivalents). Becasue of that you need to do this the hard and ugly way.

The following will work for your 3 levels, buts gets pretty cumbersome if you need a lot more depth in the tree. Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61f7c/29)

```
SELECT  C.MAILSHOT_ID
        ,C.MAILSHOT_PARENT
        ,C.MAILSHOT_NAME
        ,C.MAILSHOT_LEVEL
        ,CASE   WHEN C.MAILSHOT_LEVEL = 0 
                THEN CAST(C.MAILSHOT_ID AS CHAR(4))
                WHEN C.MAILSHOT_LEVEL = 1 
                THEN CONCAT(CAST(C.MAILSHOT_PARENT AS CHAR(4)),"..",CAST(C.MAILSHOT_ID AS CHAR(4)))
                ELSE CONCAT(CAST(P.MAILSHOT_PARENT AS CHAR(4)),"..",CAST(C.MAILSHOT_PARENT AS CHAR(4)),"..",CAST(C.MAILSHOT_ID AS CHAR(4)))
        END AS SORT_ORDER    
FROM    MAILSHOT C
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        MAILSHOT P
ON      P.MAILSHOT_ID = C.MAILSHOT_PARENT       
ORDER BY CASE   WHEN C.MAILSHOT_LEVEL = 0 
                THEN CAST(C.MAILSHOT_ID AS CHAR(4))
                WHEN C.MAILSHOT_LEVEL = 1 
                THEN CONCAT(CAST(C.MAILSHOT_PARENT AS CHAR(4)),"..",CAST(C.MAILSHOT_ID AS CHAR(4)))
                ELSE CONCAT(CAST(P.MAILSHOT_PARENT AS CHAR(4)),"..",CAST(C.MAILSHOT_PARENT AS CHAR(4)),"..",CAST(C.MAILSHOT_ID AS CHAR(4)))
        END
```

Comment: This is genius! Thanks very much for this Declan.  I really appreciate this. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for other people's suggestions of including SQL data samples  I'll do that in future, to make it easier to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical example for a hierarchical table, which is easier to query in oracle, but that's beside the point. @Declan_K gave you a good answer to achieve what you want. If you were looking for an alternative that gives you a slightly different by still well organized output, you could try this approach:

```
SELECT m1.mailshot_name AS lev1n ,           
       m1.mailshot_id AS lev1,
       m1.mailshot_parent AS lev1p,
       m2.mailshot_name AS lev2n,
       m2.mailshot_id AS lev2,
       m2.mailshot_parent AS lev2p,
       m3.mailshot_name lev3n,
       m3.mailshot_id lev3,
       m3.mailshot_parent AS lev3p
FROM mailshot m1
LEFT JOIN mailshot m2 ON m2.mailshot_parent = m1.mailshot_id
LEFT JOIN mailshot m3 ON m3.mailshot_parent = m2.mailshot_id
WHERE m1.mailshot_parent = 0;
```

Gives output:

```
+----------+------+-------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+------+-------+
| lev1n    | lev1 | lev1p | lev2n     | lev2 | lev2p | lev3n       | lev3 | lev3p |
+----------+------+-------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+------+-------+
| England  |   49 |     0 | London    |  140 |    49 | Wimbledon   |  300 |   140 |
| England  |   49 |     0 | London    |  140 |    49 | Westminster |  310 |   140 |
| England  |   49 |     0 | York      |  149 |    49 | NULL        | NULL |  NULL |
| Scotland |   56 |     0 | Glasgow   |  191 |    56 | NULL        | NULL |  NULL |
| Scotland |   56 |     0 | Edinburgh |  493 |    56 | NULL        | NULL |  NULL |
+----------+------+-------+-----------+------+-------+-------------+------+-------+
```

Good summaries on how to deal with hierarchical data in MySQL can be found here:
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Comment: This is clever stuff. I'm sure I'll be able to use this, or something like it, on future project. Thanks for the contribution and for the links. StackOverflow community is just brilliant!